# Use sed/awk to remove pattern from repeating lines

Tags: awk, sed

I have the following pattern in a file

```
TREE(abc/x73/APPLE)   DEST(MYFILE.FILE1A) 
TREE(abc/x74/APPLE)   DEST(MYFILE88.FILE1A) 
TREE(abc/x100/APPLE)  DEST(MYFILE100.FILE1B) 
TREE(abc/x61/APPLE)   DEST(MYFILE1000.FILE1A)
```

I would like the output to ideally be:

```
TREE(abc/x73/APPLE)   FILE1A
TREE(abc/x74/APPLE)   FILE1A
TREE(abc/x100/APPLE)  FILE1B
TREE(abc/x61/APPLE)   FILE1A
```

However, I'll be ok with:

```
TREE(abc/x73/APPLE)   DEST(FILE1A)
TREE(abc/x74/APPLE)   DEST(FILE1A)
TREE(abc/x100/APPLE)  DEST(FILE1B)
TREE(abc/x61/APPLE)   DEST(FILE1A)
```

I've tried variations of

```
sed 's/\(FILE1A\).*/\1/'
```

but I just keep getting the same as the input. I'd appreciate any pointers as to where I'm going wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
cat test.txt
TREE(abc/x73/APPLE)   DEST(MYFILE.FILE1A)
TREE(abc/x74/APPLE)   DEST(MYFILE88.FILE1A)
TREE(abc/x100/APPLE)  DEST(MYFILE100.FILE1B)
TREE(abc/x61/APPLE)   DEST(MYFILE1000.FILE1A)

sed -n 's/\(.*)\).*\.\(.*\))/\1\t\2/p' test.txt
TREE(abc/x73/APPLE) FILE1A
TREE(abc/x74/APPLE) FILE1A
TREE(abc/x100/APPLE)    FILE1B
TREE(abc/x61/APPLE) FILE1A
```

Explanation:

`-n` option - don't print everything

`\(.*)\)` first capture group - everything up to and including the first ")"

`\.\(.*\))` second capture group - everything between "." and the last ")"

`\1\t\2/p` print the first captured group, then a tab, then the second capture group

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/MYFILE[[:digit:]]\{0,\}\.//' file.txt
```

---

Output

```
TREE(abc/x73/APPLE)   DEST(FILE1A)
TREE(abc/x74/APPLE)   DEST(FILE1A)
TREE(abc/x100/APPLE)  DEST(FILE1B)
TREE(abc/x61/APPLE)   DEST(FILE1A)
```

---

```
sed 's/DEST.\{1,\}\.//;s/)$//' file.txt
```

---

Output

```
TREE(abc/x73/APPLE)   FILE1A
TREE(abc/x74/APPLE)   FILE1A
TREE(abc/x100/APPLE)  FILE1B
TREE(abc/x61/APPLE)   FILE1A
```

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK`'s for this task as follows, let `file.txt` content be

```
TREE(abc/x73/APPLE)   DEST(MYFILE.FILE1A) 
TREE(abc/x74/APPLE)   DEST(MYFILE88.FILE1A) 
TREE(abc/x100/APPLE)  DEST(MYFILE100.FILE1B) 
TREE(abc/x61/APPLE)   DEST(MYFILE1000.FILE1A)
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="DEST\\([[:alpha:][:digit:]]*\\.|\\)[[:space:]]*$"}{print $1 $2}' file.txt
```

output

```
TREE(abc/x73/APPLE)   FILE1A
TREE(abc/x74/APPLE)   FILE1A
TREE(abc/x100/APPLE)  FILE1B
TREE(abc/x61/APPLE)   FILE1A
```

Explanation: I set field seperator (`FS`) to value which hold two alternatives (sheared by `|`)

- `DEST(` zero or more alphanumerics dot (`.`)
- `)` followed by zero or more whitespaces (your file has trailing
  whitespaces) and end of line (`$`)

As `(` and `)` and `.` have special meaning I need to escape them to get literal `(` and literal `)` and literal `.` which I need. I `print` content of value 1st column (which is `TREE(`...`)` and trailing whitespaces) concatenated with value of 2nd column which is `FILE1A` and so on.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` you can get the two results:

First output with `gsub()` function:

```
awk '{gsub(/^[^.]+.|)$/,"",$2)} 1' file | column -tc2
TREE(abc/x73/APPLE)   FILE1A
TREE(abc/x74/APPLE)   FILE1A
TREE(abc/x100/APPLE)  FILE1B
TREE(abc/x61/APPLE)   FILE1A
```

or second output with `sub()`:

```
awk '{sub(/MYFILE[[:digit:]]*./,"",$2)} 1' file | column -tc2
TREE(abc/x73/APPLE)   DEST(FILE1A)
TREE(abc/x74/APPLE)   DEST(FILE1A)
TREE(abc/x100/APPLE)  DEST(FILE1B)
TREE(abc/x61/APPLE)   DEST(FILE1A)
```

and using `column -tc2` you can keep (or adjust) the spaces between columns.

Answer (score 0):

You might also use a bit more specific pattern, and use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to match any char except parenthesis between the opening and closing parenthesis.

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\([^()]*\)[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*` Match from the first opening `(` till closing `)` and the following spaces or tabs
- `)` Close group 1
- `[^()]*` Optionally match any char except `(` and `)`
- `\(` Match the second opening parenthesis
- `[^()]*\.` Match any char except `(` and `)` and then a dot
- `([^()]*)` Capture any char except `(` and `)` in **group 2**
- `\)` Match the second closing parenthesis

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cJpKFh/1) for the capture groups.

```
sed -n 's/\(([^()]*)[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*\)[^()]*([^()]*\.\([^()]*\))/\1\2/p' test.txt
```

Output

```
TREE(abc/x73/APPLE)   FILE1A 
TREE(abc/x74/APPLE)   FILE1A 
TREE(abc/x100/APPLE)  FILE1B 
TREE(abc/x61/APPLE)   FILE1A
```

---

If the format of the data is always as in the example data, using gnu awk you could also capture the last alphanumeric characters before the closing parenthesis of the second field, and use a tab as an outut field separator.

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '
match($2, /([[:alnum:]]+)\)/, a){print $1, a[1]}
' test.txt
```

Output

```
TREE(abc/x73/APPLE)     FILE1A
TREE(abc/x74/APPLE)     FILE1A
TREE(abc/x100/APPLE)    FILE1B
TREE(abc/x61/APPLE)     FILE1A
```